# Java 8 lambdas using if else on list stream

Tags: java, lambda

I have a following production ready java 8 method; which

- iterates over a list
- filters based on predicate
- if finds 0 method based on filter, throw `RuntimeException` with message 1.
- if finds more than 1 method based on filter, throw `RuntimeException` with message 2.
- else return the found method itself

I achieved what I wanted using some lambda magic with 90s `if else`...

```
private Method getEventHandler(Class listener, Class<? extends Event> event) {
    List<Method> methods = asList(listener.getMethods())
            .stream()
            .filter(method -> shouldHandleEvent(method, event))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());

    if ( methods.size() == 0 ) {
        throw new RuntimeException("No event handlers");
    } else if ( methods.size() > 1 ) {
        throw new RuntimeException("More than one handler.");
    }

    return methods.get(0);
}

private boolean shouldHandleEvent(Method method, Class<? extends Event> event) {
    return method.getParameterCount() ==1 && 
           method.getParameterTypes()[0].isAssignableFrom(event);
}
```

If I had only two conditions, where I would be checking for exact 1 or more/less than 1, I could have written code as below,

```
private Method getEventHandler(Class listener, Class<? extends Event> event) {
         return asList(listener.getMethods())
            .stream()
            .filter(method -> shouldHandleEvent(method, event))
            .findFirst()
            .orElseThrow(() -> new RuntimeException("No event handlers"));
}
```

But, I've three conditions to check and I'm trying to act as if I live in 2016, so trying to use lambda to replace the `if else` in the first method, so that it is even more cleaner.

My guess is something as below,

```
private Method getEventHandlerProposed(Class listener, Class<? extends Event> event) {
      return asList(listener.getMethods())
            .stream()
            .filter(method -> shouldHandleEvent(method, event))
            .collect(Collectors.toList())
            .stream()
            .count() == 0 -> throw new RuntimeException("No event handlers");
            .or
            .count() > 1 -> throw new RuntimeException("More than one handler.");
            .orElse()
            .findFirst()
            .get();
}
```

I am sure it's not possible as I am suggesting but looking for some neat lambda that could make it look better and make me happy.

Comment: .NET (speficially, LINQ 2 Objects) has a function .Single which does pretty much exactly what you want to do (throw if count !=1). https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb155325(v=vs.100).aspx Not sure if there's an equivalent in Java, but should be easy to implement.

Comment: Well, I think you are trying to say something as `.findFirst()` - https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#findFirst-- in java that returns the first element of the `sequence` or an empty `Optional` is `sequence` is empty.